# Can you query/write to a MySQL database from apex code?

Tags: apex, database

Is it possible to work with a MySQL database directly from Salesforce? If not, is the main approach to create some sort of web service to sit in the middle between the two?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not possible directly, salesforce does not allow TCP connections which would be required to directly connect to mysql. It only allows HTTP(S) callouts, so an intermediate webservice of some sort if required to proxy the HTTP(S) traffic to the mysql protocol.

Comment: This is what I thought but I'm glad you could help to confirm it, thanks.

Comment: @ca_peterson, any changes on this? I know we can do it in Java, for instance, and make call from apex to my Java program. But directly from apex?

Comment: No way to call anything other than HTTP from apex. You can't implement a binary protocol like mysql needs.